# RxJS in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new at RxJS and Angular.

There are two http requests. If the first one is succeed, the next one should be executed. If the first fails or returns wrong data - we should emit an error immediately. I've wasted several hours to make it using RxJS but without success.

**The first request** (`service.ts`)

```
  login(form): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, form)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

**The second one** (`service.ts`)

```
  makeSiteLogin(form): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, form, {responseType: 'text' as 'text'})
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

As a AngularJS/jQuery programmer, I didn't find better way than to check results of this request in a component (controller). I guess it would be better to check result in a service. `component.ts`:

```
this.loginService.login(this.userForm).subscribe(data => {
  if (data && data.ssid) {
    this.loginService.makeSiteLogin(this.userForm).subscribe(data2 => {
      if (data2) {
        alert('good');
      } else {
        alert('another error');
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('an error');
  }
});
```

As you see, I'm nesting functions and call `this.loginService.makeSiteLogin` if the first request successes. It's easy but I think is far from perfect. If I use Observables this way, they are useless.

I guess I should use `switchMap` but how can I check all the results by that way?

In a controller I want just one service function call and it should return success result of the second function (the condition that all is complete) or an error. I don't care what function threw an error.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: subscribe can take 2 functions as parameters like a promise first is successful response and second is an error response. .subscribe(successFuntion(), errorFunction())

Comment: please rephrase the title of your question as its way to vague

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenation of Angular http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702140/concatenation-of-angular-http-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your usecase you can use `flatMap`, `switchMap`, or `concatMap` with a pattern like this.

```js
this.loginService.login(this.userForm)
    .switchMap(data => {
        if (!data || !data.ssid) {
            return Observable.throw('First login failed');
        }

        return this.loginService.makeSiteLogin(this.userForm)
    })
    .subscribe(data => alert('good'), error => alert('bad'));
```